# How to prevent when calling a command in a shell function?

Tags: shell, tmux, fzf

I have the following function that I'm writing:

```
tmux() {
  if [ "$1" = "menu" ]; then
    if [ ! -n "$TMUX" ] && [[ $(tmux ls | head -n 1) == *"created"* ]]; then
      selection=$(tmux ls | fzf -m | cut -f 1 -d " ")
      tmux attach -t ${selection: : -1}
    fi
  else
    command tmux $@
  fi
}
```

The purpose of this is to pipe `tmux ls` into `fzf` to generate a menu for selecting a tmux session.

This works fine, but if I don't want to select anything and I press `CTRL-C` it returns:

`tmux:4: substring expression: -1 < 0`

Is there anyway to suppress this or prevent it from printing the the first place?

Comment: Is this from the `tmux attach` line? Can't you just skip that line with an if statement after looking at `$selection`?

Comment: Ha! That did the trick. You should post your answer.